# bitmap won't appear in form

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am trying to make a bitmap appear in my form, but it won't work.

my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    gfx.Clear(Color.Red);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        gfx.DrawRectangle(pen, i + 50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put a PictureBox on your Form and assign a new Bitmap? Drawing on the Form itself will lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: Nothing in this code is attempting to draw a bitmap. You're drawing rectangles on an in-memory bitmap, but you don't draw the bitmap itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code is doing is drawing to a bitmap, in memory. You don't have any code to actually display that bitmap anywhere.

You could modify the code to paint the bitmap onto the form, but as nvoigt suggested in comments, a better solution would be to use a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. When you create your bitmap, you can assign that bitmap to the picture box's [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
// render bitmap

pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

If you absolutely must draw on the form itself, you can override the form's [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e40ahaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, and use the graphics object's [DrawImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to render your bitmap there.